# Produce several items in Spring Batch chunk-tasklet

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm new to SpringBatch. I'm configuring a `<chunk>` tasklet with reader/writer/processors. I want to produce -for each read item- zero or more command-items that the writer executes.

AFAIK the ProcessorItem interface only let me produce one item for each read item or null. Of course I can produce List but I would like a cleaner approach.

Maybe I'm not using the right tool and there's another thing for not one-to-one-related readers/producers vs. writer/consumers... but I don't know.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to produce -for each read item- zero or more command-items that
>   the writer executes.

afaik there is no *right* direction yet, i see 2 possible solutions:

1. use a wrapper ItemReader to wrap the real reader and split items as needed
   (needs temp. data to work)
2. use the ItemProcessor and the mentioned
   workaround with List as return value

i would go with the itemProcessor, it would be the first part of a spring batch program i would look for such transformation logic

Comment: As an addendum, there's a pretty simple example [in the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors).